# cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError) while running rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production command

Tags: ruby, faye, private-pub

I am referring to the [pub railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub) and have followed all steps properly but while running last command i.e.

```
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
```

to rackup the faye server I am getting following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
```

Comment: Have you already installed `thin` (using `gem install thin`, or via `bundler` and the `Gemfile`)?

Comment: Ran into same issue rack only supports thin and not puma?

Answer (score 13):

Have you already installed thin?

You can install a gem using the `gem` command:  `gem install thin`

Or alternatively use Bundler, add `thin` to the `Gemfile` then run `bundle install` (of course you will need the [`bundler` gem](http://gembundler.com/) for this)

Comment: This answer should have been accepted; seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem: Here is how you fix it. Go into your current rails directory type the following: 1. sudo gem install faye,  2.  sudo gem install thin.

The chances are you didn't install it local to your new rails project.